# Form HTML > PHP > SQL > Email

Tags: php, html, forms

Here's the HTML Code I have for the form fields.

It needs to be read by the PHP so that a SQL table `idE` reads it and bounces that infomation to an email account.  Server connection (connect.php works fine).

I am getting a white blank screen upon submitting the forms with no results.

HTML

```
<div class="pure-u-ss-1 pure-u-lg-1-2">
    <div class="grey form">
        <form id="dealerform" method="POST" action="../dealerform.php">
            <input id="dfr1" type="hidden" name="retailer" value="0" />
            <input id="dfex1" type="hidden" name="experience" value="0" />
            <input id="dfl1" type="hidden" name="locations" value="0" />
            <input id="dfa1" type="hidden" name="assets" value="0" />
            <div class="two column row">
                <div class="input item">
                    <label>First Name*</label>
                    <div class="field box"><input id="dffname" name="firstName" type="" /></div>
                </div>
                <div class="input item">
                    <label>Last Name*</label>
                    <div class="field box"><input id="dflname" name="lastName" type="" /></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="two column row">
                <div class="input item">
                    <label>E-mail Address*</label>
                    <div class="field box"><input id="dfemail" name="email" type="" /></div>
                </div>
                <div class="input item">
                    <label>Phone Number</label>
                    <div class="field box"><input name="phoneNumber" type="" /></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="two column row">
                <div class="input item">
                    <label>Address</label>
                    <div class="field box"><input name="address" type="" /></div>
                </div>
                <div class="input item">
                    <label>City</label>
                    <div class="field box"><input name="city" type="" /></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="two column row">
                <div class="input item">
                    <label>State</label>
                    <div class="field box"><input name="state" type="" /></div>
                </div>
                <div class="input item">
                    <label>Zip</label>
                    <div class="field box"><input name="zip" type="" /></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="two column row">
                <div class="input item">
                    <label>Company Name</label>
                    <div class="field box"><input name="companyName" type="" /></div>
                </div>
                <div class="input item">
                    <label>Available Liquid Assets</label>
                    <div class="fleft assets select box" data-id="dfa1" data-form="dealerform" data-value="1" onclick="selectCheckboxSet(jQuery(this))">Yes</div>
                    <div class="fright assets select box" data-id="dfa1" data-form="dealerform" data-value="0" onclick="selectCheckboxSet(jQuery(this))">No</div>
                    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="two column row">
                <div class="input item">
                    <label>Existing Wireless Retailer?</label>
                    <div class="fleft retailer select box" data-id="dfr1" data-form="dealerform" data-value="1" onclick="selectCheckboxSet(jQuery(this))">Yes</div>
                    <div class="fright retailer select box" data-id="dfr1" data-form="dealerform" data-value="0" onclick="selectCheckboxSet(jQuery(this))">No</div>
                    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="input item">
                    <label>Years of retail experience</label>
                    <div class="fleft experience select box" data-id="dfex1" data-form="dealerform" data-value="1" onclick="selectCheckboxSet(jQuery(this))">0-2</div>
                    <div class="fcenter experience select box" data-id="dfex1" data-form="dealerform" data-value="2" onclick="selectCheckboxSet(jQuery(this))">2-5</div>
                    <div class="fright experience select box" data-id="dfex1" data-form="dealerform" data-value="3" onclick="selectCheckboxSet(jQuery(this))">5+</div>
                    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="two column row">
                <div class="input item">
                    <label>Types of products you offer:</label>
                    <div class="field box"><input name="typeProducts" type="" /></div>
                </div>
                <div class="input item">
                    <label>Carrier services you offer:</label>
                    <div class="field box"><input name="carrierServices" type="" /></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="two column row">
                <div class="input item">
                    <label>Number of retail locations:</label>
                    <div class="fleft locations select box" data-id="dfl1" data-form="dealerform" data-value="1" onclick="selectCheckboxSet(jQuery(this))">0-2</div>
                    <div class="fcenter locations select box" data-id="dfl1" data-form="dealerform" data-value="2" onclick="selectCheckboxSet(jQuery(this))">2-5</div>
                    <div class="fright locations select box" data-id="dfl1" data-form="dealerform" data-value="3" onclick="selectCheckboxSet(jQuery(this))">5+</div>
                    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="input item">
                    <label>How did you hear about us?</label>
                    <div class="field box"><input name="howHearAbout" type="" /></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="centered row">
                <div class="input item">
                    <div class="submit button" onclick="validateSubmitDealer()"><img class="btn ready" src="img/form_submit_button.png" /><img class="btn over" src="img/form_submit_button_over.png" /></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

PHP

```
    <?php
    mail($recipient, $subject, $headers, $howHearAbout);

if($_POST["submit"]) {
    $recipient='haseeb.shaida@stjacques.com';
    $subject="Become a dealer inquiry";
    $headers = 'From: PrepaidPrograms@SimplyPrepaidDealer.com';
    $dffname=$_POST['firstName'];
    $dflname=$_POST['lastName'];
    $dfemail=$_POST['email'];
    $phoneNumber=$_POST['phoneNumber'];
    $address=$_POST['address'];
    $city=$_POST['city'];
    $state=$_POST['state'];
    $zip=$_POST['zip'];
    $companyName=$_POST['companyName'];
    $dfa1=$_POST['assets'];
    $dfr1=$_POST['retailer'];
    $dfex1=$_POST['experience'];
    $typeProducts=$_POST['typeProducts'];
    $carrierServices=$_POST['carrierServices'];
    $dfl1=$_POST['locations'];
    $howHearAbout=$_POST['howHearAbout'];


}

?>

<?= isset($thankYou) ? $thankYou : 'Did not send' ?>

<?php

if(valid) {
    jQuery('#dealerform').append(
        jQuery('<input />')
         .attr('type', 'hidden')
         .attr('name', 'submit')
         .attr('value', 'true')
    ).submit();
}

?>

<?= isset($thankYou) ? $thankYou : 'Did not send' ?>

<?php include("connect.php"); 

?>
```

ValidateSubmit() JS

```
function validateSubmitDealer() {
    var valid = true;
    // check form values here
    var fname = jQuery("#dealerform #df-fname").val();
    if( fname === '' ) {
        valid = false;
        jQuery("#dealerform #df-fname").parent().addClass('error');
    }
    var lname = jQuery("#dealerform #df-lname").val();
    if( lname === '' ) {
        valid = false;
        jQuery("#dealerform #df-lname").parent().addClass('error');
    }
    var email = jQuery("#dealerform #df-email").val();
    if( email === '' ) {
        valid = false;
        jQuery("#dealerform #df-email").parent().addClass('error');
    }
    if( valid ) {
        jQuery('#dealerform').submit();
    }
```

Comment: what's the php_error.log saying about the blank screen? Any output there?

Comment: @Andreas refers to your http servers error log file...

Comment: also please check the php manual for the mail function defintion. I think you might have a problem there.

Comment: Don't have an http servers error log file @arkascha

Comment: Please check your http servers configuration where the log file is located. You most certainly _do_ have such error log file.

Comment: Your HTML doesn't appear to have an input named "submit", so nothing would get emailed out. What does "validateSubmitDealer()" do?

Comment: @ChrisForrence bump.. validateSubmitDealer() confirms the firstName, lastName, email are entered in the fields

Comment: @arkascha I do, meant to say, do not have access

Comment: How do you want to develop on a system without having access to the error log file? That means you will spend 90% of your time _guessing_...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your HTML doesn't actually include any inputs named "submit", so the if-statement in your PHP file will evaluate to false.

You can fix this by adding an input when you submit the form as such:

```
if(valid) {
    jQuery('#dealerform').append(
        jQuery('<input />')
         .attr('type', 'hidden')
         .attr('name', 'submit')
         .attr('value', 'true')
    ).submit();
}
```

---

Additional observations:

- It also appears that you are not actually using `$thankYou`; try printing it within your PHP file before/after the include statement.

  ```
  <?= isset($thankYou) ? $thankYou : 'Did not send' ?>
  ```
- It looks like you're setting many variables, but not using them consistently. Take the following line, for example:

  ```
  $mailBody = "Name: $df-fname\nEmail: $senderEmail\n\n$message";
  ```

  `$df`, `$senderEmail` and `$message` are *all* undefined variable names. Furthermore, this variable is not used. You should either remove the line or fix it:

  ```
  $mailBody = "Name: {$dffname}\nEmail: {$dfemail}\n\n{$howHearAbout}";
  ```
- You seem to have mixed up the `mail` parameters; the message comes before additional headers.

Comment: Added the if(valid) { .. } and removed the $thankYou.. no result. ): @chrisForrence

Comment: Why did you remove `$thankYou`? I suggested that you attempt to print it out so that you can see if it emailed or not.

Comment: When you updated the code, it looks like you put the jQuery snippet in the PHP code; it should replace the `is( valid )` part instead.

Comment: @christForrence just to confirm the function validateSubmitDealer() { code should be entirely replaced with the if(valid) { code or be added additionally to the code parse.